# hi i want to create first row automatically when i create the table in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs, entity, nest

I want to create the first row automatically when I create the table
in nestjs
want to create the first row automatically when you create a table in NestJS using TypeORM
how to do it in nestjs if anyone know please help me out

Comment: There is no such in-built function. However, you can create a script that will help you create a new table and you can insert the default values to the table after you create it. You can keep another table where you can mark these script as completed so you won't run them twice.

Comment: You could implement a custom seeder that will run on application startup - trigger the seed method from `main.ts` and that method should check if the table is empty, and if it is then create and save a new entity to it